# list of ints up to sqrt n in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and want to faktor an integer by trial division up to its square root.

Trying this snippet on replit.com:

```
firstfaktor n = head [x | x <- [2.. floor (sqrt n)],  n `mod` x == 0]
          
main = do
  print $ head [x | x <- [2.. floor (sqrt 91)],  91 `mod` x == 0]
  print $ firstfaktor 91
```

I'd expect the second print to have the same output as the first namely 7, but it doesn't work and I don't understand the long error message.

Answer (score 4):

Your `firstfaktor` uses `n` twice: once in `sqrt n`, where it requires the type of `n` to be a type of the `RealFrac` typeclass, and once for `` n `mod` x `` where it requires the type of `n` to be an instance of the `Integral` typeclass.

While technically possible to make a number type that is an instance of both, it does not make much sense to do that. You can make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert an item of a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass to any `Num` type, so we can use this with:

```
firstfaktor :: Integral a => a -> a
firstfaktor n = head [x | x <- [2.. floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n))],  n `mod` x == 0]
```

The function will however still raise an error if it can not find any faktor for the given number.

A simpler option might however be to take items as long as the square of these items is less than or equal to `n`, so:

```
firstfaktor :: Integral a => a -> a
firstfaktor n = head [x | x <- takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= n) [2 ..], n `mod` x == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had your second version in mind but couldn't get it to run. There'll be quite a lot to learn. For the case no faktor is found I have added `++ [n]` to the list so it's never empty.